# Joomla / PHPMyAdmin bug when "select" is in the value

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin, mariadb

## Background

We recently changed over from one server to a brand new one.

Old server: PHP 5.7, Joomla 2.x, MySQL 5.6.x

New Server: PHP 7.0, Joomla 3.x, MariaDB 10.x.

The OSE Plugin is the different, but given that it is affecting rows outside of OSE (They seem to be defunct now, as we are not getting any reply from their support staff).

On both servers, this glitch can be replicated, but not 100% of the time.

## The Issue

Near as we can tell, any value that is entered into the table that contains "select", "selected", or any other variation of the word results in a generic 500 error. This happens when changing an article that includes the word, when changing an email template in the OSE control panel (e.g. "membership selected:"), or when trying to change those rows manually through a PHPMyAdmin installed manually.

Curiously, when logging into the PHPMyAdmin through the installed cPanel, we can change those values there. This obviously isn't a long term solution as we can't give our writers cPanel / PHPMyAdmin access, but I mention it to help understand the whole picture.

## What we tried

Error Logs - No Error logs (that we can find) show anything related to this issue.

Permissions - Permissions don't seem to affect this issue, as we can make changes to any value, as long as they don't include "select" or any variation of that name.

## The Goal

What I want to understand is why the cPanel PHPMyAdmin can make these changes, but not the manually installed one, or Joomla / OSE.

Comment: It sounds like a misguided attempted to prevent SQL injection by inherently rejecting content that contains SQL reserved words. Does the same behavior occur with the words `update` or `delete`?

Comment: Just tried. `update`, and `delete` work fine, but `select` causes a 500 error.

Comment: Is the website hosted in a shared hosting plan? Are there more firewalls in play here? If you try to replicate the request (same get and post values) but to a different endpoint (maybe outside of wordpress) does it still show a 500 error?

Comment: This is on a locally owned corporate server. All firewalls have been checked. And this is Joomla, not WordPress. There are 2 versions of PHPMyAdmin we have installed, One behind cPanel (which can make any changes we want) and another we manually installed (which does not work). Additionally, the Joomla control panel itself gives this error when adding `select` to any article.

Comment: @ZLHysong I see that you don't yet have a JoomlaStackExchange account.  You should come over and repost your question.  You may get an informed response from the dedicate support community there. (Although if you are playing the rep-point game, you should earn 200 points here first, then create your JSX account so that you start with more privileges.)  I've got no trouble upvoting this question, it is well crafted and full of details.

Comment: Done, I [moved the question over there](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/23411/joomla-phpmyadmin-bug-when-select-is-in-the-value). Should I delete it here, or just let it die and people can redirect from here to there?

Comment: Well, based on FFrewin's answer, I guess there is nothing Joomla-specific to correct.  (of course, I didn't know that before recommending)  I say leave both posts and see if you get support from either network.  If you manage to self-solve and find that the answer is Joomla specific, then you can post an answer over there.  If you find that the solution is not Joomla specific, you can post an answer here and tell FFrewin that you'd like the JSX question to be removed as Off-topic Not Joomla-related.

Comment: Understood. I mentioned this there, but I'll try FFrewin's solution this weekend or early next weekend and post results here. And I agree, if it is not Joomla after all, we can close it as Off-Topic there.